# How to parallelize I/O operations when there is no async API

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm working on an application that scans servers remotely and collects meta data about them.

I'm trying to be write code that scales nicely on our servers. I'm using TPL to process multiple jobs at the same time. The problem that I have is that each of these 'jobs' spends half its time waiting for I/O operation to complete.

This would be very easy to fix if those operations offered Async or Begin/End interfaces but they don't. Couple samples:

- System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl
- Win32API calls such as FindFirstFile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx and FindNextFile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx

How can I ensure that my application does more in this scenario? Should I create wrappers for these so that Async is supported and that way they will get send for processing in a thread.
Should I try TPL implementation Producer/Consumer so that all those I/O calls are executed at the same time? Will the TPL be smart enough to create more threads since most of them will not be doing anything?
Or maybe inside each of these jobs I should add job to ThreadPool for processing?

Comment: Why not just start a Task that does the job you want? BTW Win32 API calls usually are fast enough that they don't need async. Those that do and DON'T have .NET equivalents usually need special handling per case, eg. special callbacks, polling

Comment: Additionally, WMI queries using the .NET API can be converted to Tasks using TaskCompletionSource. Can you give some examples of Win32 and WMI calls you need to run asynchronously?

Comment: Some Win32 API calls do offer async interfaces, except that they don't follow .Net conventions. That's exactly how e.g. asynchronous `FileStream` operations are implemented.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Starting a `Task` still means that a thread is blocked, so it's not likely going to help.

Comment: I did say that they need special handling. As for whether executing a blocking operation asynchronously helps? It depends on the scenario, which is why I asked for specifics. Running 10 ops in parallel is better than 10 sequentially, but running 100 may not be feasible. I don't think you can make broad assumptions without knowing the specifics

Comment: To simplify things lets asume these two: System.Io.Directory.GetAccessControl and Win32Api FindFirstFile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx. I am calling these hundreds of times. There is no async support for those and they are not quick since they access remote machines. How can speed them up? Maybe use threadpool to process all of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're spending most of your time in IO-bound operations that don't have asynchronous equivalents, then the only way to speed them up is to use multiple threads that are blocked most of the time.

But depending on the nature of that IO, you might not get any speedup at all. For example, if the IO is accessing a local disk, then using a single thread is most likely going to be the most efficient option. On the other hand, if you're accessing remote computers and you're not bound by your network bandwidth, then using many threads might be the best option.

TPL sounds like the right solution, but which part of TPL depends on your code. Maybe processing multiple jobs at the same time using `Parallel.ForEach()` will be the right solution. Or maybe you'll want to run some parts of a single job in parallel using `Task`s. It's hard to say without knowing more details.

> Should I create wrappers for these so that Async is supported and that way they will get send for processing in a thread.

No, don't do that. If you start a blocking `Task` on another thread and then release the current thread using `await`, then you haven't gained anything (assuming this is a server application). For more information, see [*Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

> Will the TPL be smart enough to create more threads since most of them will not be doing anything?

Yes, the TPL tends to use more threads if the current ones are blocked. But at the same time, you most likely want to limit the number of threads (usually by setting something like `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`), depending on the kind of IO you're doing.